# logic problem in javascript - 2 requirements array/object

Tags: javascript

```
const data = [
    { name: "Table", color: ["green", "red", "blue"], price: 300 },
    { name: "Desk", color: ["white", "yellow", "grey"], price: 300 },
    { name: "Desk", color: ["black", "pink", "green"], price: 500 },
];
```

Hello, I'm trying to code buy-list in objects, but I met logic problem here because for example, there can be same object (called Desk) but with different array (color) for different price.

How can I grab info about price if my script will meet 2 requirements - it will be Desk, color will be black for example, and result needs to be 500
using .find() function returns 1st object (in this case:  { name: "Desk", color: ["white", "yellow", "grey"], price: 300 })

Please help :D
Greetings.

Comment: surely you've tried to write some code to accomplish this, can you add it to your post please so we can better help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for the wanted color.

As result you get either an item or `undefined`, if the request does not match.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Table", color: ["green", "red", "blue"], price: 300 }, { name: "Desk", color: ["white", "yellow", "grey"], price: 300 }, { name: "Desk", color: ["black", "pink", "green"], price: 500 }],
    request = { name: 'Desk', color: 'black' },
    result = data.find(({ name, color }) =>
        name === request.name &&
        color.includes(request.color)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: everything works fine, thank you so much for help & clean code

Answer (score 1):

Given just the information your data has you either need to come up with a cumbersome approach like trying to find the color as well, or make sure to include a unique identifier like a SKU into your objects.

Comment: any idea/example how can I handle my idea of buylist? maybe I should use only arrays?